# what the word appreciate could mean here

Tags: verbs, word-in-context

*UPDATED*:
 Before coming to the city for school, she never had any **exposure to** the arts.

Before coming to the city for school, she has never had the opportunity to appreciate the arts.

The reading book " inside reading 3" expresses the fact the both of the sentences are synonym.

Hence, I am wondering what the bold word could mean? or would you explain it or give a proper synonym for it in such a way that I could get its meaning more vividly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [exposure](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/exposure#exposure_15) "the act of providing someone with the opportunity to experience new ideas, activities, etc." (approx. *experience*); [appreciate](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/appreciate) "to recognize the good or special qualities of a person, place, or thing" (google for "art appreciation" for more info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appreciate here means [*to understand* or *to be aware of*](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/appreciate).

It's an intellectual use of the word, you'll see it used like that in a formal context or when knowledgeable people talk about arts, for instance.